# Hide SDL Tridion sub Folder based on permissions

Tags: content-manager

Recently we have created two user groups, group Editor A and Editor B. These two groups works for different sites and have different permissions.

Inside SDL Tridion, there are two sub folders under the Building block folder, Folder A and Folder B. We want to let Group A only see Folder A, and Group B only see Folder B.

If we use permissions to control the access, we can set it so hat Group B can't open Folder A and view the sub folders, but Group B still can view Folder A itself.

Does anyone know how to handle this part?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll find that the default behavior is consistent with most systems out there, in particular with Windows Explorer.

The reason why the folder is not hidden is for performance reasons - it is faster to display a list if we don't need to filter it for security.

You can modify this behavior, and make Tridion hide the folders that editors do not have access to, by:

- Opening the SDL Tridion Content Manager Configuration "Snap-In" on the server
- Open the node named "General Settings"
- Change the value of "Hide organizational items if no access to content" to 1 instead of 0 (the default)

Restart your server. Now, editors should not see any folder or Structure Group that they do not have access to. You should monitor for any visible performance impact.